# Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null after implementing session cookies in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I implemented cookie sessions on my firebase project using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) link. 
I'm trying to get the `idToken` in the client side to send it to server side.
Here's the code I'm using on client side:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/checkSession",
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status === "ok" && data.user){
                const user = data.user;
                const emailVerified = user.email_verified;
                const uid = user.uid;

                if (emailVerified){
                    firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(uid).child("username").once("value", snapshot => {
                        const username = snapshot.val();
                        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {
                        // Doesn't work...
                        })
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

And here's the server that checks for the session:

```
app.post("/checkSession", (req, res, next) => {
    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
    admin
        .auth()
        .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true)
        .then(user => {
            res.json({
                status: "ok",
                user
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
            })
        });
})
```

Everything works except this function: `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {...})` and it's throwing `Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null` error.

UPDATE: Here's the sign-in method I'm using. I'm passing false to `httpOnly` and `secure` since I'm testing it locally.

```
app.post("/SignInUser", (req, res, next) => {
    const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 10 * 1000; // 10 days

    admin
        .auth()
        .verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(function (decodedClaims) {
            if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedClaims.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
                return admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn });
            }
        })
        .then(function (sessionCookie) {
            const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: false, secure: false};
            res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
            return res.json({
                status: "ok"
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: "Unauthorized request!"
            })
        });
})
```

UPDATE 2: I use the idToken to verify that the request coming from is actually from the user and not from an external source, here's an example code:

```
function getUserSnapshotOrVerifyUserId(username, idToken, cb) {
    if (username == null || username.length == 0 || idToken == null || idToken.length == 0)
        return cb({
            status: "error",
            errorMessage: "Missing params."
        }, null);

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(decodedToken => {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;

        admin.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.exists())
                return cb({
                    status: "error",
                    message: "invalid-profile"
                });

            snapshot.forEach(child => {
                const id = child.val().id;
                if (id !== uid)
                    return cb({
                        status: "error",
                        message: "Invalid ID"
                    });

                admin.database().ref("users/" + id).once("value", snapshot => {
                    if (!snapshot.exists())
                        return cb({
                            status: "error",
                            errorMessage: "user not found."
                        });

                    return cb(null, id, snapshot);
                });
            });
        });
    }).catch(err => cb({
        status: "error",
        message: err
    }));
}

app.post("/getUserProfile", (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username || req.query.username;
    const idToken = req.body.idToken;

    getUserSnapshotOrVerifyUserId(username, idToken, (err, id, snapshot) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);

        let userdata = {
            username: snapshot.val().username,
            name: snapshot.val().name,
        }

        res.json({
            status: "ok",
            userdata
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you check if "firebase.auth().currentUser" is not null?

Comment: @SergeyReus Yes it's null! Even though there's a session present in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase auth is asynchronous and you need to wait for it to fully initialize before trying to reference `currentUser`.  Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742270/how-to-store-data-under-specific-user-id-angularfirebase/66743693#66743693) for more information on how to do that.

To put it into simpler terms, you need to listen to `onAuthStatusChanged()` and wait for it to return `null` or a `User` object before calling any function that references `currentUser`.  I'd give you specific code changes but the relevant section isn't in the question.

Comment: Firebase auth is not triggering since I'm not using the main authentication functionality of firebase, I'm using cookie sessions.

Comment: I'm not certain that you're implementing Firebase Auth correctly.  On the client side you need to Authenticate, if not already (`signInWith_____()`) -> Wait for auth status update with `onAuthStatusChanged()` -> Get ID Token -> Call /SignInUser passing the ID token which sets the cookie. Your error is caused because you're either not waiting for the SDK to initialize *or* the user isn't authenticated.  If you follow that example in my other answer where you don't call `/checkSession` until `onAuthStatusChanged()` has given you a definitive auth status, it will work, promise!

Comment: BTW, the only code that's relevant here is your client side code.

Comment: But their official documentation doesn't use `onAuthStatusChanged()`, and yes the user is being authenticated, I checked.

Comment: Their official documentation as in this one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: The documentation only shows the initial authentication.  If you implement it as-is, then refresh the page `currentUser` will be null if you don't wait for the SDK to initialize.  The *only* two reasons `currentUser` would be null is if the user isn't authenticated *or* you haven't waited for the SDK to fully initialize.

Comment: Okay so what's the solution? Using `onAuthStatusChanged()`?

Comment: The solution is in the answer above.  Just replace the AngularFire `this.afu.authState` with `firebase.auth().onAuthStatusChanged` in the example if you're not working with Angular.